# jQuery Chosen: change event doesn't fire from AJAX call

Tags: jquery, onchange, html-select, jquery-chosen

I'm using jQuery [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) on my page and I want to run a function every time a new option is selected. The function hides all of the child `div`s in a parent `div`, then shows just the one that corresponds to the option that was selected.

HTML:

```
<select id="settings-select" data-placeholder="Choose&hellip;" class="chzn-select">
    <option value="setting1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="setting2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="setting3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="setting4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="setting5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="setting6">Option 6</option>
</select>

<div id="settings-tabs">
    <div id="setting1" class="tab">...</div>
    <div id="setting2" class="tab">...</div>
    <div id="setting3" class="tab">...</div>
    <div id="setting4" class="tab">...</div>
    <div id="setting5" class="tab">...</div>
    <div id="setting6" class="tab">...</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var settingsShow = function(){
    var showPanel = $("#settings-select").find('option:selected').val();
    $("#settings-tabs .tab").hide();
    $("#" + showPanel).fadeIn("fast");
    alert(showPanel);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#settings-tabs .tab").hide();
    $("#settings-select").chosen().change(settingsShow);
});
```

All of this works fine so far – when the selected item is changed, `settingsShow` is called (and an alert displays just to confirm this).

Now, I also have an AJAX call that changes the selected option when it completes:

```
$("#settings-select").val("setting1").trigger("liszt:updated");
settingsShow();
```

Here's the problem: once the selected option is changed by the completed AJAX call, selecting the previously-selected option no longer fires the change event. For example:

1. Select "Option 2": displays alert "option2"
2. Perform AJAX call: upon completion, selects "Option 1" and displays alert "option1"
3. Select "Option 2": nothing happens

I know it's an issue with Chosen specifically because it works fine if I use a normal `select` instead (at step 3 above, I'll get an alert that says "option2", like I should). But as you can see, I'm using `.trigger("liszt:updated")` to update the `select` when the AJAX call changes the selected option, so I don't see why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is a legitimate bug in Chosen 0.9.8 (the current release version). I updated to the [cutting-edge version](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/tree/master/chosen) (not officially released) and the problem corrected itself with no other changes.